# Android - WebRTC: Video call live drawing

Tags: android, canvas, drawing, webrtc

I am trying to make a simple feature with WebRTC on an Android (mobile) app.
The app right now can make a simple video call: connect two devices with each other and allow them to hear and see.
What I am trying to achieve is some live drawing during the call. To put it simply: User1 call User2, the call gets connected, then User1 click on a draw button which will freeze the video frame and allow him to draw on this frozen frame. Obviously, User2 should see this drawing happening live on his phone.
Right now I can freeze the frame (by calling videoCapture.stopCapture()) and draw on it with a custom SurfaceViewRenderer. The problem is that User2 does NOT see the drawing, only the frozen frame.

First I tried to create a new videotrack containing the drawing canvas AND the frozen frame to draw on but I couldn't succeed. 
When creating a videotrack with `peerConnectionFactory.createVideoTrack("ARDAMSv1_" + rand, videoSource);` 
I am supposed to specify the video source of the track but the source can only be a `VideoSource` and this VideoSource can only be created with a `VideoCapturer` which is directly linked to a device camera (without any drawing on it of course). This explains why User2 is not seeing any drawing on his device.
My question here is: how can I create a VideoCapturer which can stream the camera stream (frozen frame) AND a canvas with the drawing on it?

So I tried to implements my own VideoCapturer to either:
1) Capture a View (for example the layout containing the drawing and the frozen frame) and stream it for the VideoSource
OR 2)Capture the camera view but also add the drawing to the frame before streaming it.
I couldn't make any of this work because I have no idea how to manipulate the I420Frame object to draw on it and return it with the right callback.

Maybe I am totally wrong with this approach and need to do something completely different, I am open to any suggestion.
PS: I am using Android API 25 with WebRTC 1.0.19742. I do NOT want to use any paid third party SDK/lib.

Does anyone have a clue how to proceed to achieve a simple WebRTC live drawing from one android app to another android app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We came back to that feature a couple weeks ago and I managed to find a way.

I extended my own CameraCapturer class to get the hold on the camera frame before the rendering. I then created my own CanvasView to be able to draw on it.

From there what I did was merging the two bitmap together (the camera view + my canvas with the drawing), then I draw it with OpenGL on the buffer and displayed it on the SurfaceView.

If someone is interested I could potentially post some code.

Comment: Could you please post some code? I have to create a similar feature, but I don't get how to do this using WebRTC SDK.

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Override
    public void startCapture(int width, int height, int fps) {
    Log.d("InitialsClass", "startCapture");

    surTexture.stopListening();
    cameraHeight = 480;
    cameraWidth = 640;
    int horizontalSpacing = 16;
    int verticalSpacing = 20;
    int x = horizontalSpacing;
    int y = cameraHeight - verticalSpacing;

    cameraBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(640, 480, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    
    YuvFrame frame = new YuvFrame(null, PROCESSING_NONE, appContext);

    surTexture.startListening(new VideoSink() {
        @Override
        public void onFrame(VideoFrame videoFrame) {
            frame.fromVideoFrame(videoFrame, PROCESSING_NONE);
        }
    });
    if (captureThread == null || !captureThread.isInterrupted()) {

        captureThread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                if (matrix == null) {
                    matrix = new Matrix();
                }
                long start = System.nanoTime();
                capturerObs.onCapturerStarted(true);
                int[] textures = new int[1];
                GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);

                YuvConverter yuvConverter = new YuvConverter();

                WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) appContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

                GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
                // Set filtering
                GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
                GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
                //The bitmap is drawn on the GPU at this point.
                TextureBufferImpl buffer = new TextureBufferImpl(cameraWidth, cameraHeight - 3, VideoFrame.TextureBuffer.Type.RGB, textures[0], matrix, surTexture.getHandler(), yuvConverter, null);

                Resources resources = appContext.getResources();
                float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;
                Log.d("InitialsClass before", "camera start capturer width- " + cameraWidth + " height- " + cameraHeight);

                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                    ByteBuffer gBuffer = frame.getByteBuffer();
                    if (gBuffer != null) {
                        Log.d("InitialsClass ", "gBuffer not null");
                        cameraBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(gBuffer);
                    }
                    if (cameraBitmap != null) {

                        if (canvas == null) {
                            canvas = new Canvas();
                        }

                        if (appContext.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
                            rotationDegree = -90;
                        else {
                            assert windowManager != null;
                            if (windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0) {
                                // clockwise
                                rotationDegree = 0;
                            } else if (windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_90) {
                                // anti-clockwise
                                rotationDegree = -180;
                            }
                        }

                        canvas.save(); //save the position of the canvas
                        canvas.rotate(rotationDegree, (cameraBitmap.getWidth() / 2), (cameraBitmap.getHeight() / 2)); //rotate the canvas
                        canvas.drawBitmap(cameraBitmap, 0, 0, null); //draw the image on the rotated canvas
                        canvas.restore();  // restore the canvas position.


                        matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
                        matrix.postTranslate(/*weakBitmap.get().getWidth()*/ cameraBitmap.getWidth(), 0);
                        matrix.setScale(1, -1);
                        matrix.postTranslate(0, /*weakBitmap.get().getHeight()*/ cameraBitmap.getHeight());
                        canvas.setMatrix(matrix);

                        if (textPaint == null) {
                            textPaint = new TextPaint();
                        }
                        textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                        textPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.create(typeFace, Typeface.BOLD));
                        textPaint.setTextSize((int) (11 * scale));

                        if (textBounds == null) {
                            textBounds = new Rect();
                        }
                        textPaint.getTextBounds(userName, 0, userName.length(), textBounds);



                        textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
                        textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
                        canvas.drawText(userName, x, y, textPaint);

                        if (paint == null) {
                            paint = new Paint();
                        }
                        if (isLocalCandidate) {
                            paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                        } else {
                            paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                        }
                        paint.setStrokeWidth(8);
                        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                        canvas.drawRect(0, 8, cameraWidth - 8, cameraHeight - 8, paint);

                        if (surTexture != null && surTexture.getHandler() != null && surTexture.getHandler().getLooper().getThread().isAlive()) {

                            surTexture.getHandler().post(() -> {

                                // Load the bitmap into the bound texture.
                                GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, /*weakBitmap.get()*/ cameraBitmap, 0);

                                //We transfer it to the VideoFrame
                                VideoFrame.I420Buffer i420Buf = yuvConverter.convert(buffer);
                                long frameTime = System.nanoTime() - start;
                                VideoFrame videoFrame = new VideoFrame(i420Buf, 0, frameTime);

                                capturerObs.onFrameCaptured(videoFrame);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Log.d("InitialsClass camera", ex.toString());
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                return;
            }
        });
    }
    captureThread.start();
}
```

@Anael. Check it out.

Answer (score -2):

I was working on a similar application, so I share the **draw on webrtc stream part**:

1. What you need to do is get the [stream to canvas](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/canvas/).
2. Then have drawing application to edit on the canvas, I look at a [William Malone](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/) project. (if you want to import pictures, make then transparent!)
3. Finally (what you missed I guess) is [stream from canvas](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/capture/canvas-pc/) as you would with any WebRTC.

A little demo I cooked up specially for you [here](https://klompmaker.duckdns.org/draw/) (local webrtc, see log).

PS: I use getDisplayMedia, not userMedia as my webcam is *kaput*...

Comment: Indeed, what I miss was captureStream().
But mostly because I specifically asked this question for Android, and this function doesn't exist on it.

This whole answer is absolutely unrelated to Android.